# Can't attach event handlers to jQuery dialog page

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dialog

I have a jquery dialog page, noted here:

```
<div data-role="page" data-rel="dialog" data-close-btn="none">
<div data-role="header">
<h2>Failed to find driver</h2>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<p>Failed to find a driver. Would you like to continue searching or cancel the search?        </p>
<a data-role="button" id="continueBtn" onclick="alert('continue')">Continue </a>
<a data-role="button" id="cancelBtn" onclick="alert('cancel')">Cancel </a>
</div>
</div>
```

These alerts work in the dialog. However, I cannot attach event handlers for other functions to these buttons. How can I attach events to these buttons?

Comment: is the contents of the dialog dynamically loaded? can you share how the event handlers are added

Answer (score 1):

don't do something this `onclick="alert('cancel')"` already as you already using jquery.. do it like this

```
$("#cancelBtn").click(function(){
    alert('cancel');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/click/

and if the contents is dynamically loaded you need to use `Jquery.on()`

```
 $("#cancelBtn")on.("click",function(){
        alert('cancel');
 });
```

Comment: The alerts were simply a test; I have found no alternative to directly placing them inside the html. the $(document).ready function doesn't run when I switch pages to the dialog.

EDIT: i accidentally pressed enter before i finished typing